# Practical difference between intensity and amplitude in SLC SAR Sentinel 1 data

Tags: sentinel-1, sar, radar

In the SLC product, amplitude data is not explicitly provided by SLC Sentinel 1, only the real (i) and imaginary (q) bands of each polarization obtained, in addition to a band called “Intensity” for each polarization.

To get amplitude would have to do:

```
Amplitude = sqrt(i²+q²)
```

The intensity is obtained by:

```
Intensity= i²+q²
```

Now, then to get the amplitude on SLC Sentinel 1 I could simply calculate the square root of the Intensity band?:

```
Amplitude = sqrt(Intensity)
```

But in practice, physically, what do amplitude and intensity represent, what are their measurement units? Why does ESA use these two notations, theoretically for the same thing?

Comment: You might find this tutorial useful - https://hyp3-docs.asf.alaska.edu/guides/introduction_to_sar/

Answer (score 1):

You can think of amplitude as measuring a voltage (in units of Volts), which is proportional to energy, while intensity represents a power (in units of Watts). The images will look similar, but some features may stand out more in one view than the other. As in the [link ycartwhelen shared](https://hyp3-docs.asf.alaska.edu/guides/introduction_to_sar/), amplitude images have a narrower dynamic range than intensity images. People use both in radar because historically, electrical engineers have been interested in measuring responses of both "voltage" and "power."